# how to use jquery fadein in text after fading in the container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is probably a very simple task but I can't seem to get it to work. I have two divs. div one is fading into div two after a slight delay. I need to fade in some text in div two, but it is not working.

my html

```
<div class="first_slide">
    <p>some content</p>
 </div>


 <div class="second_slide">
  <h4 class="byline">need to fade in</h4>
  </div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".first_slide").delay(10000).fadeOut(1200);
$('.second_slide').delay(11000).fadeIn(1200);
```

I need the `h4` in the second div to fade in. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('.second_slide').delay(11000).fadeIn(1200, function(){
    $('.byline').delay(11000).fadeIn(1200);
});
```

Comment: it should work, but it isn't. this is the first thing I tried. Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: I'm a huge idiot! the `display:none` was commented. I must have did that to debug and forgot to turn back on. it's working now. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
     $('.second_slide').hide();
    $(".first_slide").delay(10000).fadeOut(1200);
    $('.second_slide').delay(11000).fadeIn(1200);
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/VzU7J/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this (Since `h4` is only child of it's parent so I faded in parent)

```
$(".first_slide").delay(2000).fadeOut(1200, function(){
    $('.second_slide').delay(2000).fadeIn(1200);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/37erd/)